# Tailwind running with Next gives a syntax error

Tags: tailwind-css

```
./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/css-loader/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].oneOf[7].use[1]!./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-loader/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].oneOf[7].use[2]!./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].oneOf[7].use[3]!./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/sass-loader/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].oneOf[7].use[4]!./styles/style.scss
/home/user/node_modules/color/index.js:257
            lum[i] = (chan <= 0.039_28) ? chan / 12.92 : ((chan + 0.055) / 1.055) ** 2.4;
                              ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

Comment: I guess you are using SCSS, Read the documentation about nextjs support for styling, https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support

Comment: I was having the same problem, my nodejs version was 10 and it must be 12+.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like it's a node version issue.
https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/921

Use Node 14 for example